# data is lost after page refresh from local storage

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am storing user info into local storage, but every time i reload the page data is lost. not getting the exact solution. Here is my js code. i am getting value for user object from html in this format

```
    {"fname":"A","lname":"B","age":"12","email":"a@b.com","class":"6","password":"1234"}
```

here is my js code

```
    var app = angular.module("myApp",["ngStorage"]);

   app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope,$localStorage,
     $sessionStorage) {
     var usersinfo= [];
     $scope.submit = function() {
       usersinfo.push($scope.user);
       localStorage.setItem("usersinfo", JSON.stringify(usersinfo));

      console.log(usersinfo);    
     };   

});
```

Comment: any error in console? try with `window.localStorage.setItem(key, value);`

Comment: @Shariq Ansari : You need to use setitem().  

$window.localStorage.setItem('user_profile',JSON.stringify(userData));
$window.localStorage.setItem('is_login',true);

Comment: use $ symbol before localStorage..

Answer (score 0):

You are importing $localStorage and using localStorage.

See [documentation](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage#read-and-write--demo) for read/write syntax.

Comment: It should not be a problem as `localStorage` is a globally available variable to access local storage.

Comment: Then why inject ngStorage in your module, if you will not use it?

Comment: yes, that can be removed. Though if you wanna maintain a consistency on the resource usage, you can keep them.

Answer (score 0):

The following example works fine when executed separately in an HTML file (Dont expect it to load localStorage in StackOverflow execution environment)

```js
var user = {
  "fname": "A",
  "lname": "B",
  "age": "12",
  "email": "a@b.com",
  "class": "6",
  "password": "1234"
};
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("MyController", function($scope) {
  console.log('Loaded');
  $scope.usersinfo = [];
  $scope.show = function() {
    $scope.usersinfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('usersinfo'));
    console.log($scope.usersinfo)
  };
  $scope.submit = function() {
    $scope.usersinfo.push(user);
    localStorage.setItem("usersinfo", JSON.stringify($scope.usersinfo));

    console.log($scope.usersinfo);
  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
    <p>Hi</p>
    <button type="button" ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
    <button type="button" ng-click="show()">Show</button>
    <p>{{usersinfo}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```